# Select element client side logic

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Okay, mb the question isn't good, but I don't know how to name the Q, so sorry about that...

I got form which communicates with the server and stores data into a database, it's a "book appointment" form, the form has 2 `<Select>`'s which have several `<options>`.

First `<Select>` has some companies with whom You can book the appointment.
Second `<Select>`'s `<option>`s is time like "9:30", "11:00" etc.

I'm trying to set the second `<Select>`'s `<option>`s to be clickable or unclickable depending on the time, so if someone else already made the appointment for Company1 at 9:00 then the option should be unavailable, but only for Company1 not for all the Companies.
Is it achievable? in the html?

Comment: I would do it like this -> when company is selected from the first <select> then make ajax call to server to get all the hours that are already in use. According to the returned result filter or disable options in the second select

Comment: Should also note that regardless of whether it's clickable or not, in the end you must check the returned information as the user can freely re-enable disabled options.

Comment: not sure what you're getting at :/
@sand well is that even possible since my <select>s are manually typed in, they aren't drawn from a DB.

Comment: @MicroDev Just because you disabled an option, doesn't mean that a user can't re-enable it, via developer tools on their browser. to send you false information, meaning that an appointment slot can be double, triple or x times booked when it shouldn't be.

Comment: so how do you fix it? Sorry for, maybe stupid questions, but I'm still learning. :S

Comment: @sand how do you make that call, ajax is a bit unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @A.Lau is right and this means that you should always validate the information on server side t0o. In short words the functionality that you want to provide to user should be dynamic. What is your server side language ? C#? If yes you should create a web service (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178(v=vs.110).aspx) to be able to make ajax calls. ///// There could be another solution that you render the information about company hours in an hidden HTML element and read it from there with javascript, but this will definitely be a problem if you have a lot of companies ...

Comment: @sand It is C# :) I have never used web services and the site I'm trying to make will last for only a day, so I don't pretty much care about possibilities of someone rebooking an appointment, anyways, how would I use ajax to see if there are taken hours for THAT specific selected company, even if I manually entered them in the <select> ?

Comment: @MicroDev you should go and read about AJAX calls and web services by yourself my friend because it is a very wide topic to discuss now. This is a sample demo https://jsfiddle.net/9807wnax/2/ I leave you now to understand the code and change it by yourself, bye now and good luck